# Setting up PHP Developing environment with DDEV andDocker on Windows, getting to tutorial page

Tags: php, docker, ddev

I used DDEV on linux now I am trying to make it run on Windows. I have successfully installed Docker and DDEV. When I am in my PHP project directory and I type : ddev launch

Then a tutorial page gets opened with this url: http://MyProjectDirectory.ddev.site/tutorial/
The Tutorial page says that i ran the following command: docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started

But I dont want to see the tutorial page I want to host my project.

I think its a bug with the ports. When I click a link on the docker tutorial page, a view of my project gets rendered or I get an 404 Error. Thats really wierd

EDIT SOLVED(but still need help):
After changing router_http_port: "80" to router_http_port: "8000" in config.yaml my project is getting hosted properly. I figured out, that the Docker tutorial page uses port 80, thats why I am getting to the Docker Tutorial page when trying to host my project. Everytime i type localhost in the url I am getting to http://localhost/tutorial/ and the Docker tutorial page shows up and says :

Congratulations! You have started the container for this tutorial! Let's first explain the command that you just ran. In case you forgot, here's the command:
docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started

This page shows up even after restarting my PC and Docker ist not running, how can I get rid of this

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for DDEV-Local is at https://ddev.readthedocs.io. There is no built-in tutorial page, and no standard site would redirect you to a tutorial.

Please read the [docs](https://ddev.readthedocs.io) and try the [DDEV-Local Quickstart](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/cli-usage/#quickstart-guides) for your CMS type.

Comment: But I am getting redirected to a tutorial page of Docker instead of my index.php file when I type ddev launch.

Comment: The URL should be: http://MyProjectDirectory.ddev.site/  and not http://MyProjectDirectory.ddev.site/tutorial/

Comment: Again, please use the Quickstart for your CMS to learn how to use ddev.  You may want to ask in one of the more interactive support channels (Slack, gitter, etc). If you can show in a gist (gist.github.com) exactly what you've done and what happens it will be helpful. https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#support-and-user-contributed-documentation